# R markdonw ioslides title page format changes

Tags: html, css, r, rstudio, r-markdown

I want to change the appearance of the very first title page that comes up when we knit to html my ioslides. This is the header of a test Rmd file:

```
    ---
    title: This test
    subtitle: that test
    author: jake
    output: 
       ioslides_presentation:
       incremental: true
       css: myCss4.css
    ---
```

What I want is to center the title (default is lower left corner) and change the color and font size. I was successful in changing the color and font size but not the location of the text....

This is the custom css I have tried:

```
    slides > slide.title-slide hgroup h1 {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 24pt;
      color:red;
      bottom: 50%;
    }
```

I have tried bottom:50%;, top=50% and few other things without success... Title text location does not change. What I code? Or is there a better way instead css?

Comment: Try including `position: absolute` and then add `top: 100px` or whatever you want.

Comment: I have tried this in the past. It moves the title down. So I just now tried top: -100px which moves the title up... I am not sure what is going on. The text also folds = 2 lines instead of one

Answer (score 6):

Try using the following:

```css
slides > slide.title-slide hgroup h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24pt;
  color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Thank you your suggestion makes the title disappear.

Comment: Seems my title disappear, too; however, the parameter you provide gives me some clue